# Is there any good way to snap to intersection?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, snapping

I'm doing a lot of cleanup work after a bad boolean action, and in this scenario, some vertices are offset somehow and what I want to do is to reconnect them to the edge they are supposed to be attached to.

[image: X marks the spot]

In the image above you can see the problem, the selected vertex is supposed to be attached to the edge I'm trying to snap to. The edge in question however is not perpendicular to the axis of the vertex I wish to snap, thus there is no telling when the vertex is accurately at the intersection of the z axis of the vertex and the edge, effectively making snap in this circumstance useless.

I think there were someone working on a GSoC with the goal on making more useful snapping, much more like wings or sketchup I believe. But since that isn't done yet, what are the workarounds to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
/Klesus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an addon called *dynamic spacebar menu* which contains a small routine that can snap the 3d cursor to the intersection of two edges, it's available in [addons contrib](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts). Here is the direct link to the [wiki page for it](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Dynamic_Spacebar_Menu) with a download.

[image]

After enabling the addon when you hit <kbd>space</kbd> a different menu will appear, you will see `snap cursor menu`, and inside that `cursor to edge intersection`

If the intersection of the two edges doesn't lie exactly on either of the two edges, then the edges are considered lines with infinite length. When two lines aren't parallel and don't truly intersect you can imagine another line drawn between these two lines at the point where they are closest to each other. The point in space halfway on the imagined line will be returned as the intersection.

Comment: Using your method sounds good too!

Comment: Wow, thank you zeffi! :)
I've actually used Dynamic spacebar menu since it was first released, but I have never seen that option before.

Comment: Aldrik, I tried your method too but it does not work. When multi-snaping it calculates the average, correct? Then it would only work if the intersection would be in the dead center of the two edges. In this case it is offset.